# Using robot_localization with correct frames

Tags: ros, sensor-fusion, visual-odometry, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Right now I'm using viso2_ros to get a set of odometry information. Viso2 publishes in the odom frame such that my rover moves in the z direction. My IMU+GPS system publishes in the odom frame such that my rover moves in the x direction. How can I reconcile these two differences?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286436/using-robot_localization-with-correct-frames./) by [OwnageManFromLOL](https://answers.ros.org/users/30394/ownagemanfromlol/) on ROS Answers with karma: 149 on 2018-03-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That sounds like what I would expect based on this explanation in the viso2_ros wiki:

> NOTE: The coordinate frame of the
> camera is expected to be the optical
> frame, which means x is pointing
> right, y downwards and z from the
> camera into the scene.

The wiki also explains:

> To be able to calculate robot motion
> based on camera motion, the
> transformation from the camera frame
> to the robot frame has to be known.

So you need to change the frame which your camera is outputting images on to be something other than odom (like /camera_link), and then you need to define the /camera_link to /base_link transform.

---

Originally posted by [stevejp](https://answers.ros.org/users/33828/stevejp/) with karma: 929 on 2018-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [OwnageManFromLOL](https://answers.ros.org/users/30394/ownagemanfromlol/) on 2018-03-26**:
Hi stevejp, thanks for your comment. I figured out what my issue was. I had accidentally set use_sim_time to false in my launch files. As a result, viso2 did not read the tf tree that I was publishing.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-06-16**:
@OwnageManFromLOL can you please write that up as an answer?